# I am stuck in writing one code. I wanted to sort one column first by integer then combination of integer and string then string

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, apply, natsort

I wanted to sort one column first by integer then combination of integer and string then string.

Below is my data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb', '1c2z45zz', 55, 3, 'et45']})
```

Below is my expected output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [3, 55, '1c2z45zz', 'et45', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']})
```

I have tried many method but all gives first combination of string and integer then integer then string.

```
import natsort

df.iloc[natsort.index_humansorted(df.name)]
```

then I tried below one.

```
max_length = max(df.name.str.len())
df['sort_name']=df.name.str.pad(max_length,'right','~')
df.sort_values('sort_name', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
```

and the last I tried.

```
df_sorted = df.astype(str).sort_values(by='A',key=lambda x: (x.isdigit(), x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) with your different conditions:

```
import natsort

# first sort by pure number
m1 = ~df['name'].astype(str).str.isdigit()
# then by strings having a number
m2 = ~df['name'].astype(str).str.contains(r'\d')
# optional: sort remaining in human sorted order
m3 = np.argsort(natsort.index_humansorted(df['name']))

out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([m3, m2, m1])]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
       name
5         3
4        55
3  1c2z45zz
6      et45
0       aaa
2       bbb
1       ccc
```

Other example:

```
        name
6          1
7          2
5          3
8          3
9          4
4          5
10         5
11         6
12      1000
3   1c2z45zz
14      et45
0        aaa
2        bbb
1        ccc
13     p_o_j
```

Comment: for below df it giving wrong output.?

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb', '1c2z45zz',5,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,1000,"p_o_j", 'et45']})

   expected output should be: 1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,1000,1c2z45zz,et45,aaa, bbb,ccc,p_o_j.

But it is giving: 
       
 5
1000
6
1
5
3
2
3
4
1c2z45zz
et45
ccc
aaa
bbb
p_o_j

Comment: @user21510116 you're right, I forgot to reverse the indexer with `np.argsort`, see update ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using key in sort_values

```
    (df.astype(str)
.sort_values('name')
.sort_values('name',key = lambda x: list(zip(x.str.isdigit(),x.str.contains(r'\d'))),ascending=False))
```

Output:

```
       name
5         3
4        55
3  1c2z45zz
6      et45
0       aaa
2       bbb
1       ccc
```